# Neural network predicts one class only

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I was implementing a neural network with the MNIST dataset, and I am having issues in terms of classifying $10$ classes. I am pretty sure the implementation of feed-forward and back propagation is correct, and I have used Xavier initialization to initialize the weights. When running mini-batch gradient descent, with only $1$ epoch, the lowest loss I have obtained with standard deviation is $0.3288$ as shown in the graph below:
[image]

Complete graph of $J(\theta)$:

[image]

Note that I'm using a zero-indexed implementation, which means $\frac{\partial{J(\theta)}}{\partial{\Theta^{(l)}}} = a^{(l)}\delta^{(l - 1)}$, and $a^{(l)} = \sigma((\Theta^{(l - 1)})^Ta^{(l)})$

The model has $2$ hidden layers with $10$ nodes each (excluding the bias term). Activation functions for layers $a^{(l)}, \text{ where } l > 0$

As my training data is normalized, normalized test data is used to test the accuracy of the model. Despite a low cost, my model only predicts one class.

You can find the source code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VQOYlj3TLKj8deDZ_ZD_JY-VVv2asaHq?usp=sharing).

To summarize, I have two questions:
$1$. What does negative cost indicate?
$2$. Why is my model only predicting one class?

Comment: Have you tried implementing just logistic regression for MNIST digit classification? That's a good warm up problem and it should give you about 92% classification accuracy.

Comment: Another thing you can do is compute the gradient of your objective function numerically (using a finite difference method) and check that the result agrees with the gradient you get using backpropagation.

Comment: In the title, why say that "cross entropy loss" predicts one class only? The cross entropy loss function is not a thing that makes predictions; rather, it is used to measure how well a predicted probability vector agrees with a ground truth probability vector. It is the neural network itself that makes predictions. The cross entropy loss function only evaluates the quality of those predictions.

Comment: This SE community might not be the best one on which to ask this question, have you tried [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I have tried computing the gradient by (J(theta + epsilon) - J(theta - epsilon)) / (2 * epsilon), the gradient was slowly approaching towards 0. (Which you can see in the notebook)

Comment: @RomainS Thanks for the advice, I'll be posting my question there.

Comment: @littleO Noted, I'll be making changes.

Comment: I can't specifically tell by your cross entropy implementation, but it looks a lot like you've implemented it expecting a softmax output, which is not the case. Cross entropy is mostly used when the final output is a probability (ie, all classes add up to 1) which is never the case if you use sigmoid. Try doing this using MSE, I'm fairly certain this is the issue.